# ProgressDialog always closes on onClick - DoubleClick not possible

Tags: android, progressdialog

The `doubleClick` implementation below works for any button in my layout. However I can't get it working with the Dialog Button, the `onSingleClick` works as expected but the dialog is dismissed right after.

Even when there is nothing on `onClick` method a hidden call to `dialog.dismiss()` seems to exist....

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
dialog.setMessage(activity.getString(R.string.msg_please_insert_card));
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DoubleClickDialogListener() {

    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    Toast mToast = Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.creditCard_tap_twice_cancel, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    @Override
    public void onSingleClick() {
        mToast.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleClick() {
        mToast.cancel();
        activity.finish(); // kill the Activity and go back to previous Activity

    }

});

dialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});

dialog.show();


public abstract class DoubleClickDialogListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    private static final long DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA = 300;//milliseconds

    long lastClickTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        long clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (clickTime - lastClickTime < DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA){
            onDoubleClick();
        } else {
            onSingleClick();
        }
        lastClickTime = clickTime;
    }

    public abstract void onSingleClick();
    public abstract void onDoubleClick();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - dialog is always dismissed after button click. There is nothing you can do about it. If you need to change this behaviour you have to write your own dialog implementation.